# do gravity shows its effect in atomic level?

Tags: gravity, atoms

how much of a effect do gravity shown in atomic level. how significant or negligible is it.
i am guessing the effect is small because the mass of nucleus and electron is small. But the distance between them is also small as well so i am confused whether the effect of gravity is taken into consideration in the study of atomic structure.